# Rearrange a python list into n lists, by column

Tags: python

I want to rearrange a list `l` into a list of `n` lists, where `n` is the number of columns.

e.g.,

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
n = 4
==> [[1,5,9],[2,6,10],[3,7][4,8]]
```

Can someone please help me out with an algorithm?  Feel free to use any python awesomeness that's available; I'm sure theres some cool mechanism that's a good fit for this, i just can't think of it.

PS The example list just happened to be ordered numbers starting at 1. That's not my actual scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is indeed a cool mechanism for this in Python: the three-argument form of slicing, where the last argument is step size.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> n = 4
>>> [l[i::n] for i in range(n)]
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

Comment: I was actually trying to use that (third slice argument) but ended up with something more complicated that didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: For Python 3: use range instead of xrange
`[l[i::n] for i in range(n)]`

Comment: @PaavoPohndorff Correct, updated.

Answer (score 1):

The following function does what you want to achieve:

```
def rearrange(seq,n):
    return [[v for i,v in enumerate(seq[x:]) if i%n==0] for x in xrange(len(seq))][:n]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
n = 4

def f(l,n):
    A = []
    [A.append([]) for i in xrange(n)] 
    [ A [(i - 1) % n].append(i) for i in l]
    return A

print f(l,n)
```

[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7], [4, 8]]

Answer (score 0):

Writing Python isn't a game of code golf, don't be afraid to use more than one line for the sake of readability.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def split_into_columns(input_list, num_of_cols=3):
    retval = [ [] for _ in xrange(num_of_cols)]      # build 3 columns
    for i in xrange(len(input_list)):                # iterate through original list
        retval[i%num_of_cols].append(input_list[i])  # place in the "modulo 3" column
    return retval

    # here's a compressed, less readable version of that for-loop
    #[retval[i%3].append(input_list[i]) for i in xrange(len(input_list))]
    #return retval

print split_into_columns(l, 3)
```