# Python multiprocessing does not process all items in a list

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following program that processes files (about 3400 depending on the time of the day). However, it seems to leave out a few, i.e., even though I feed it ~3400 files, it'll only process ~3100, for instance. Here's the code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

def split_list(L, n):
    return [L[i::n] for i in xrange(n)]

def coreFunc(myarg):

    listlen = len(myarg)
    print "listlen = ", listlen

    for listiter in range(listlen):
        input1 = (myarg[listiter]).rstrip('\n')
        print "input1 = ", input1

    return 1

if __name__=="__main__":

    fptr = open("myfilelist")
    array = fptr.readlines()

    numC = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    lists = split_list(array, numC)
    p = Pool(numC)
    p.map(coreFunc, lists)

    p.close()
    p.join()
```

The "myfilelist" is a text file that contains the filenames of those ~3400 files like this:

```
    /home/user/file1
    /home/user/file2
    /home/user/file3
    ….
```

It leaves out about 300 files each time I run the program. The files left out are not always the same. It varies it each run.

Any idea why these files are being left out? I verified that it is nothing to do with the field themselves by using a different set of files, by rearranging the names of the files in the "filelist", etc, but nothing seems to work. There is no error message either.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be hitting the maximum limit of file descriptors? resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE

Comment: The code in your post is not the code that you're running. Never transcribe; copy and paste from a running source file.

Comment: Sorry I can't post it - it's "clearance required" code and I can't do that unfortunately. However, even if I comment out the code in the coreFunc() function, I still get the same error. So, what you see above is pretty much it.

Comment: Please fix your post as much as possible. `define` is not python-speak; nor is `[l[i::n] for i in xrange(n)]`. Really, all we need is a minimal working example that demonstrates the issue that you are facing

Comment: I repaired some obvious errors in the code, but it doesn't really help - the real problem is in something you *haven't* shown us.  The overall structure of the code is fine, and "should work".

Comment: I tried the resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12705695/3866741 is where I got the [l[i::n] for i in xrange(n) segment. Sorry about the define.

Comment: Ok, I made the changes so that it's a minimal working example. I run it and sometimes, it'll print out 8 "listlen = …" lines, sometimes it'll print 7. It seems to be random. It's when it prints 7 that I miss out on processing all those files using listiter. This happens even if I comment out the "print "input1 = …" line

Answer (score 1):

I've made a version of the code which is directly runnable. This revised code also gives process-specific logging, which helps to see what's going on.

Hope this helps!

### source

```
import logging, multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

def split_list(L, n):
    return [L[i::n] for i in xrange(n)]

def coreFunc(mylist):
    proclog = multiprocessing.get_logger()

    proclog.info("listlen = %d", len(mylist))
    for path in mylist:
        proclog.info("input1 = %s", path)

    return 1


if __name__=="__main__":

    if 0:
        array = [line.rstrip() for line in open("myfilelist")]
    else:
        import string
        array = string.uppercase

    mylog = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    mylog.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    numC = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    lists = split_list(array, numC)

    p = Pool(numC)
    print p.map(coreFunc, lists)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

### output

```
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] listlen = 7
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = A
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = E
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = I
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = M
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = Q
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = U
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = Y
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] listlen = 6
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = D
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] listlen = 6
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = H
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] input1 = C
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] input1 = G
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = L
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] listlen = 7
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = P
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] input1 = K
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] input1 = B
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] input1 = O
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = T
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] input1 = X
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] input1 = S
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] input1 = F
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] input1 = W
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] input1 = J
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] input1 = N
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] input1 = R
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] input1 = V
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] input1 = Z
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] process shutting down
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] process shutting down
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] process shutting down
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] process shutting down
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It helps but my problem is not fully solved. With your code, I run the program and sometimes, it'll spin off all 8 PoolWorkers but sometimes it'll only start 6 or 7. Totally random. (I have an 8-core CPU. Thanks.